# How exactly is a VPC used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I understand the main concept and high level architecture of VPC. From what I understand VPC is mainly used to lower level detailing of the network. This is mainly used for ec2 instances. I understand that ec2 instances are IAAS.

My question is how the VPC is used with other resources that are PAAS or FAAS. What would be the difference between having a resource like RDS,EB, Lambda in a VPC vs not having it in a VPC? If these resources are used in a VPC are they shown through ec2 instances? Or is the mainpoint of having it in a VPC being able to control the network details to that resource?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A VPC is a **virtualized version of a physical network**.

Think about your home network. Each device in your home needs to either **physically connect to your router**, or connect via wifi to a router. Let's ignore wifi for now.

If two devices in your home want to talk to each other, they need to be connected to the same network. You cannot connect to your neighbour's devices because they are on a different network.

Your router can also connect to the Internet, allowing the devices to access computers outside your home.

The same is also true for a VPC. Any resources that wish to communicate with each other (eg EC2, RDS) **need to be on the same VPC**. If the VPC is connected to the Internet via an Internet Gateway, they can also communicate with anything accessible via the Internet.

- **Amazon EC2 instances** are always connected to a VPC. (There's an old version called EC2-Classic, but let's ignore that)
- **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** deploys Amazon EC2 instances, so they are also connected to a VPC.
- **Amazon RDS instances** use EC2 "behind the scenes", so they are always connected to a VPC.
- **AWS Lambda functions** are **optionally connected to a VPC**. If they are *not* connected to a VPC, then they can access the Internet directly. If they *are* connected to a VPC, then they can only access resources within the VPC — a NAT Gateway is required to give the function access to the Internet.
- **Amazon S3** is a web service that is always running and always accessible from the Internet. You can 'use' it, but you don't 'create' it. Therefore, it does not connect to the VPC. To use it, resources on the VPC (eg EC2 instances) need to be able to access the Internet, or use a "VPC Endpoint" that connects directly to S3 from the VPC.

The VPC is used purely to give the resources "physical" connectivity, just as if they were plugged into the same router. It grants no access within the resource itself. Think of it like you plugging your laptop into my home network — it does not grant me access to your laptop unless you have configured your laptop to permit access (eg to a disk share).

Comment: if RDS uses ec2 instances on the lower level, is it possible to connect to the RDS through the ec2 instance (access os)  as we would have access to that RDS in a VPC? Or is the fact that a resource is on a VPC different from the abstraction of that resource and how we can connect to it?

Comment: No. Amazon RDS is provided as a fully-managed service. While it uses EC2 "underneath", those instances are not accessible to users. You can control the RDS _service_ via the console or API calls and you can connect to the database via the normal database port, but you cannot connect to the OS on which the database is running. It's more that it is "using EC2 technology", rather than "using EC2".

Comment: vpc has nothing to do with abstraction of a resource. just communication. this is what im getting?

Comment: Yes, VPC is purely used for connectivity between resources.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, A VPC is completely private virtual networking service. In this private network, you'll be able to create subnets and organise them as you want, like having some networks that can have public IP adresses (frontal services for example), and other that are completely private (RDS for example).

Now, a public subnet is only called public because it is connected to an AWS resource called Internet Gateway, so your public IPs will be routed. It means that even if you have a public IP on a EC2 instance in a subnet that is not attached (via a route table) to an internet gateway, you won't be able to connect to the internet.

If you want your instances in a private subnets to be able to talk to the rest of the world, you'll have to add an AWS NAT gateway that will do the packet translation for you (the easiest way).

Now the point of having a VPC is to own the data ongoing in your stack, for example you don't want critical databases and backend services to be exposed on the internet even if you can protect them with a security group.

A lambda function in a VPC will be a resource that will be given to a Network Interface (ENI) during its execution in the subnet that you specify. This will allow you to connect to your resources that are not exposed to the internet (RDS, Elasticache, ...)

Generally you'll want to use lambda without outside of the VPC if you don't need to access to your private resources that leaves inside your VPC.

Comment: even if a resource like a lambda or rds is in a vpc, I still wont have access to its os right? in other words I can't see the lambda or rds as an ec2 instance?

Comment: Nope you can't, AWS shared responsibility model https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score -1):

A virtual private cloud (VPC) is a secure, isolated private cloud hosted within a public cloud. VPC customers can run code, store data, host websites, and do anything else they could do in an ordinary private cloud, but the private cloud is hosted remotely by a public cloud provider. (Not all private clouds are hosted in this fashion.) VPCs combine the scalability and convenience of public cloud computing with the data isolation of private cloud computing.

Imagine a public cloud as a crowded restaurant, and a virtual private cloud as a reserved table in that crowded restaurant. Even though the restaurant is full of people, a table with a "Reserved" sign on it can only be accessed by the party who made the reservation. Similarly, a public cloud is crowded with various cloud customers accessing computing resources – but a VPC reserves some of those resources for use by only one customer.